# Return 2D vector using pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, return

all

I am using a 2D vector to return my results from a function to main. The 2D vector is very large, and the function is excuted 10K+ times, thus I have to return it using pointer to speed it up.

Here is my code:

```
vector<vector<double>>* someFunction()
{
    vector<vector<double>> results;
    //do something...
    return &results;
}
```

and in main:

```
int main()
{
    // do something
    ////////// EDIT: vec is a pointer, I missed * at first place
    vector<vector<double>>* vec = someFunction();    // vec is empty!

    cout<<vec.size();        // size = 0

    return;
}
```

When I check the value and size of vec in main, it turned out that vec is size 0.

May I know what am I wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Regards

Long

Comment: 1. does it compile ? 2. RVO will probably remove the copy, so you can just return by value

Comment: @Andrew Yes, it compiles, but when excute it, since I need to write the results to files, it trigger some break point.

Comment: NEVER return a pointer to a local variable!

Comment: in C++11 you can use move semantics for this!

Comment: You can add a reference parameter to the function

Comment: @Apokal Still RVO first then move if needed

Comment: It doesn't compile. someFunction returns pointer but you don't dereference it.

Comment: What is RVO ( Return Value Optimalization)?

Comment: @hetepeperfan optimizes away some copies when returning a local variable from a function by value. You can wiki it.

Comment: search [C++] RVO in the search box on the top right

Answer (score 6):

You are returning a pointer to a local variable. This variable ceases to exist when the function scope is exited, leaving you with a dangling pointer. This is *undefined behaviour*.

Just return a value:

```
vector<vector<double>> someFunction()
{
    vector<vector<double>> results;
    //do something...
    return results;
}
```

If you are worried about expensive copies involved in returning by value, bear in mind that it is extremely likely that these will be elided via [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) (RVO), specifically named return value optimization (NRVO). Even if this doesn't happen (it is optional, so implementations can decide not to do it), in C++11 move semantics would kick in. Moving an `std::vector<double>` is extremely cheap.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not returning a reference to a local variable here, therefore going out of scope? Make it a member of the class, assuming its in a class

Alternatively pass the reference into the function as a parameter

```
void someFunction(vector<vector<double>>& results)
{
    results.clear();

    //do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you return a pointer to vector. remove the * in the method:

```
vector<vector<double>> someFunction()
```

and of course return the vector, not a pointer to it

Answer (score 0):

There appears already to be a popular answer, but there is a way to do exactly what your asking using dynamic memory allocation. I feel like this is worth pointing out since, although it may not be the best way to approach this particular problem, dynamic memory allocation is a very useful technique in general. The idea is that "someFunction" should create a pointer to a dynamically allocated piece of memory which will hold the `vector<vector<double>>`. Here is working code using smart pointers but one could instead use the traditional `new` and `delete`  keywords for allocation also if c++11 is not your thing:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

shared_ptr<vector<vector<double>>> someFunction() {
  vector<vector<double>> result;
  //Do stuff with result                                                                        
  shared_ptr<vector<vector<double>>> resultPtr =
    make_shared<vector<vector<double>>>(result);
  return resultPtr;
}

int main() {
  shared_ptr<vector<vector<double>>> ptr;
  ptr = someFunction();
  return 0;
}
```

Like I said it may not be the best way, but let it be known that returning a pointer to a local object can indeed be done correctly using dynamic memory allocation.